# Numpy array and change value regions

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for replacing zones in array, for example I create an array `b = numpy.zeros((12,12))`. And I want to change its values with `a=numpy.aray([[1,2],[2,3]])` in the left upper corner indexed by `[0:1,0:1]`.

When I specify `b[0:1,0:1] = a` I have an error:

```
"ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled".
```

What's the method to do such thing ?

Thanks

Comment: `numpy` uses the same conventions as Python for slicing. For the basics of Python slicing, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/577088).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use correct indices:

```
>>> b[0:2,0:2] = a
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html):

> One way to remember how slices work is to think of the indices as
>   pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character
>   numbered 0. Then the right edge of the last character of a string of n
>   characters has index n, for example:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | H | e | l | p | A |
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5
-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Comment: That's it! I don't really understand why because i want to replace the index 0 and 1 (fon example in one line). Why is it necessary to go to index 2 ?

Comment: @user1187727 Because `2` denotes the end of the second element (see the scheme at the end of my answer). So [0:2] is actually the first and the second elements of the sequence.

Comment: Ok nice response ! Thank you very much !